# How can I undo more than a single character in TextMate?

Tags: macos, plugins, editor, textmate

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) may be the best editor out there, but is has a big disadvantage: it undoes each character typed instead of grouping characters. This makes a large undo tedious!

Do you now any hacks, plugins or workarounds to fix this issue?

Comment: Gee, that kinda sucks.  :)  I don't know any other popular editor that suffers from this flaw.

Comment: It smarts a little, since a lot of us paid for TextMate, as it is amazingly good in general. But I've had a paid copy for over 18 months and this issue is still not fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  know the developer's been promising a fix for years now, and it's something the user community complains about a lot.  But I don't think I've seen anything more useful than "hold down Cmd-Z to repeat".

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you're asking for but more a work around because as dnord said, this is a fundamental issue with TextMate and won't be fixed until Allen Odegard decides to fix it.

Have you considered trying one of the clipboard managers out there? At least that way you can clip chunks of text and 'undo' them at will.

I use [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/) because it's free and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone doesn't already know this:  Shift-Option-Arrow lets you select things word by word.

If you make a habit of selecting whole words before deleting text, you'll save time when you do and when you undo.